# required input fields on a html form

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a html form with required input fields. but its not responding. below is the code

```
        <div class="col-sm-6">

            <label for="city" class="form-control">city
                <input name="city" type="text" id="city" class="form-control" required>
            </label>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                valid city is required
            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: What is not responding? Did you build proper form, or just put some fields randomly on the page?

Comment: @zoldxk The [required attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required) does not take a value - including the attribute name within the input tag is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

If by "not responding" you mean that a user can submit the form without entering a "City" value, it may be because you [need a `<form>` element around form controls](https://codepen.io/geoffdavis92/pen/rNjjdZw) in order to allow browsers' default behavior for `required` inputs to work correctly.